# How to use JavaScript, Ajax or jQuery to display array data in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Right now I am getting the data like this which works fine but I want to auto display it in a table. I have a button which is clicked and should display the result into a table or should create the table and display any way would be fine.

```
$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $result[$i][0] = $row['fname'];
    $result[$i][1] = $row['lname'];
    $result[$i][2] = $row['membershipid'];
} 

return $result;
```

any help will be great

Comment: Replace the php code that you´re showing us with the result of the ajax request, and we may help a little bit. If you can put your code into a fiddle it will be better.

Comment: You will probably want to use `json_encode()` in your PHP and `JSON.parse()` in your Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a data structure of

```
[
 {
  fname:"john",
  lname:"doe",
  membershipid: "1234"
 }    
]
```

This function should work for n rows of data

```
function createTable(dataArray){
 var table = document.createElement('table');
 var tablerows = dataArray.map(function(datarow){ 
     var tablerow = document.createElement('tr');
     for (var value in datarow){
       var cell = document.createElement('td');
       cell.innerText = datarow[value]; 
       tablerow.appendChild(cell);
     }
     return tablerow;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < tablerows.length; i++){
    table.appendChild(tablerows[i]);
  }

   return table;
}
```

Then

```
var table = createTable(dataArray);
document.getElementById('Whatever dom node').appendChild(table);
```